# How do I configure Serilog in appsettings.json to create log file in UTF-8-BOM encoding?

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, serilog

The default file encoding that Serilog creates is utf-8 without BOM. How do I configure Serilog in appsettings.json to create log file in UTF-8-BOM encoding?

If i add "encoding": "utf-8", I get an error "InvalidOperationException: Type UTF8 was not found."

```
"WriteTo:Async": {
  "Name": "Async",
  "Args": {
    "configure": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/Log-.txt",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 5242880,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 31,
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz}] [{Level:u3}] ({ThreadID}) [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "encoding": "utf-8",
          "formatter": {
            "type": "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: With
```
"encoding": {
  "name": "utf-8"
}
```
 , I get an error 
InvalidOperationException: Cannot create instance of type 'System.Text.Encoding' because it is either abstract or an interface.

Comment: **Why** on earth would you _want_ the UTF-8 BOM? (It's non-standard, [discouraged by everyone](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/297), and means you can't concatenate files together because you need to trim the BOM first)

Comment: I'm using cmtrace (Microsoft Configuration Manager Trace Log Tool) to read logs. If the log file is not in utf-8-bom encoding, then there are problems with special characters

Answer (score 0):

The manner that you has used to specify the encoding is incorrect. You must provide **a valid full qualified existing encoding class name** or inherit from an existing or create a custom one.

In this case, you only need to create a derived class of `System.Text.UTF8Encoding.` Follow these steps:

1. Create a derived class of `System.Text.UTF8Encoding.` Passing `true` on the base constructor we are setting `encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier` parameter and this change the encoding behavior to UTF-8 BOM encoding.

```
using System.Text;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public class UTF8WithBOMEncoding : UTF8Encoding
    {
        public UTF8WithBOMEncoding() : base(true) { }
    }
}
```

2. On `appsettings.json` specify **the full qualified class name and the assembly name** of the encoding class to use. If you don't provide both elements the internal type resolution will fail.

```
{
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
        "encoding": "MyApplication.UTF8WithBOMEncoding, MyApplication",
    }
}
```

---

**TL;DR This notes it's only an explanation of the type resolution behavior**

The type resolution occurrs in this line of code [Serilog.Settings.Configuration - StringArgumentValue.cs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/1d0e7bfc2e950ce3924714773c08ef707de9b17c/src/Serilog.Settings.Configuration/Settings/Configuration/StringArgumentValue.cs#L137).

```
var type = FindType(argumentValue.Trim());
if (type == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Type {argumentValue} was not found.");
}
```

The [`FindType` method](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/1d0e7bfc2e950ce3924714773c08ef707de9b17c/src/Serilog.Settings.Configuration/Settings/Configuration/StringArgumentValue.cs#L160) uses the `Type.GetType` method, according the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-8.0#system-type-gettype(system-string)) this method will try to resolve the type searching on the currently executing assembly or in `mscorlib.dll` or `System.Private.CoreLib.dll.`

```
internal static Type? FindType(string typeName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    if (type == null)
    {
        if (!typeName.Contains(','))
        {
            type = Type.GetType($"{typeName}, Serilog");
        }
    }

    return type;
}
```

Because our application it's using the Serilog package to resolve the Serilog configuration, **all the operations occurrs in the context of the Serilog Assembly,** that is because we must provide explicitly the assembly name where the custom encoding class exists.